# specflow step definitions in separate assembley

Tags: specflow

I have two projects - "Features" containing specflow features and "Steps" containing Specflow step definitions.
I have the following setting in "Features" project app.config

```
<specFlow>
<!-- For additional details on SpecFlow configuration options see https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Configuration -->
<stepAssemblies>
  <stepAssembly assembly="Steps" /> 
</stepAssemblies></specFlow>
```

But when i try to debug my feature file I get this error:
    Could not load file or assembly 'Steps' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

what am I missing? Is it not possible to specify features and steps in two separate assmeblies? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

sorry I got it ! Forgot to add the reference to project "Steps" in the "Features" project